# How can you say that a sensor system uses three different types of sensors?

Tags: word-request

How can you say that a sensor system uses three different types of sensors? I thought about the composite word triple-sensors, but it doesn't sound like a word that would be used in a technical document.

> The triple-sensors system can detect all sorts of threat through the
>   use of thermal, imaging and radar detection technologies.

I can't think of a good adjective for this.

Comment: Are you looking for a word like *multimodal*? (Not saying that's it…)

Answer (score 2):

I would write:

"A system with three sensor types ... "

Saying "a triple sensor system" (or similar) strongly implies that all three sensors are of the exact same type.

Answer (score -1):

**Divergent** (Adjective)

-Tending to be different or develop in different directions.

> Divergent thinking!

I would suggest you to use something like:

> Triple divergent sensors

Defining both 3 sensors in usage and all differs from each other.

Comment: To me that would connote that the sensors tend to disagree.

Comment: In science "divergent" ideas is wellcome yet for people who would like to see it with a negative meaning "it is an upcoming argument".